# magento2. Get SQL string frontend search

Tags: magento2, search

When a user makes a search on a site(where search product), I would like to see SQL request this search. How can I see him?

[image]

Comment: Donot understand  your question.

Comment: Didn't get the question. Brief the question

Comment: when a user makes a search on a site(where search product), I would like to see SQL request this search. How can I see him?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is just to do some quick debugging you can log all SQL by editing vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php and in function _query() after where you see

```
$result = parent::query($sql, $bind);
```

Add the line

```
file_put_contents("my.log", $sql, FILE_APPEND) ;
```

Run the search and then look in the website root for your log file (it will be pretty large)